# build ios app so ipad uses iphone screen size

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I have inherrtied an IOS project that was being built primarly for iphone. When I run the app on an ipad, the app runs in the top left corner of the screen and everything looks a bit broken. I noticed some apps run in a small iphone screen on the ipad with the option to zoom in. How do I get my app to do this?

Comment: Make sure it is a non-Universal, iPhone only app and remove any checks & code for the UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad.  When run on an iPad it should then behave as you want.

Comment: In addition to @Mike's answer, you MAY need to delete the storyboard or xib out of the project with the suffix "_iPad."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the project settings and select your target. Under the "Summary" tab, choose "iPhone" from the "Devices" dropdown:

[image]

Comment: This helped me fix a display issue that I spent days wrestling with.  Thanks!