# How to achieve a Fixed Layout Design in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Please explain me how to achieve such fixed design as you can see on the screenshot below:
[image]

I mean that I need to display applications on the iPad in landscape or portrait mode as if it were running on a mobile device.

Comment: What have you tried already? Where have you searched already? Why hasn't it worked? Including these in your question helps us quicker answer your question and make it more relevant and useful to you. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more help on asking questions, and consider reading [Layouts in Flutter](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/layout) and [Basic Flutter layout concepts](https://docs.flutter.dev/codelabs/layout-basics) regarding help for your question. StackOverflow isn't a free code writing service ;) Best of luck!

Comment: Just from a quick glance it looks like it could be a Stack() at the top level, with various Wrap() widgets as children to build the numpad section.

Comment: @dwb Thank you so much. But I am here just to listen other opinions not for a ready-made solution. Because I have no clue how to do it.

Comment: @CStark Thank you too. I think it will be a good solution. I will try it.

Comment: Do you need explanation on keypad layout? Pls clarify in more detailed description what exactly you want

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11086427/build-ios-app-so-ipad-uses-iphone-screen-size).
You just need to select only `iphone` mode in `devices` dropdown in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

For system orientation, in Flutter you can **lock** how the app is presented with this code:

```
SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
   [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]
);
```

For the UX, I recommend you use space dividers, to make sure the app has a consistent look between all devices, even if their aspect ratio is slightly different.